# SQL table with many columns or more 1:1 tables?

Tags: design, database-design, sql

What is better solution? Eg. an object has a lot of single settings. Keep all these settings in one table or divide these features and store in separate tables with relation 1:1? Some features are required for all objects, other only for specific types of objects.
One solution could be store all required fields in table objects and the rest in table objects_extras? 
"Objects" is just an example name.

Comment: I programmed in a situation that had a base table and then 4 - 8 subclass tables (different customers had wildly different data layouts). There are many reasons to break up tables in this way including performance. If you have 8 subclasses, and 10-50 relevant columns applicable only to each subclass, one big table will seem like a dumb idea in a hurry.

Comment: What are the field types for the settings? Having 50 columns of a bit isn't as bad as 25 blobs.

Answer (score 2):

> Some features are required for all objects, other only for specific types of objects. One solution could be store all required fields in table objects and the rest in table objects_extras?

Only you can decide this, based on the [data] needs of your objectd.

You could stick with one table that includes everything, presumably with nullable entries for those that don't apply to all objects.  It's simplest and easiest to maintain.

Or, you could go with a "sub-classing" design, with a core table with all the common stuff, plus a number of other, "extra" tables, one for each subclass of object.  It's not much more complex to manage but it might give you *some* performance benefits if each subclass has a *lot* of custom fields (and you never use "select *" in your queries).

Or, you could go to the *extreme* and head down the road (rabbit hole?) of Entity-Attribute-Value.  That gives you *complete* flexibility of which property goes with which object, but comes at the price of [potentially very] poor scaling, but I suppose it's still an option.

My suggestion: prototype each method and see how each one feels.

Answer (score 1):

Though the problem with a table with many columns in RDBMS was hard limits of number of columns (looking at you Access) in tables and a big hit on usage of disk and memory.

Those problems are not that big anymore, but there is still a big problem of handling the large number of columns in the code. Beyond even as little as 10-15 columns in a table, maintenance can become a nightmare unless you can hide the full number of columns behind an abstraction (ORM, homemade or framework).

Once you go away from having to know all about a table everywhere you use it, things become far easier.

There are three strategies on hierarchies of objects with different attributes but some common information.

Table-per-hierarchy:

One table with all columns.

Table-per-type:

One base table each type has its own table with foreign key to the base table.

Table-per-concrete-type:

Each type has its own table.

This is an article on how to do things in [Entity Framework](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph) you can find similar articles based on the RDBMS or framework you want to use.